# Есть ли разница или как лучше вызвать функцию

Tags: javascript, функции

Есть ли разница или как лучше вызвать функцию?

1. В условии функция вызывается `(function(){})()`

   ```
   var intevalID = setInterval(function(){
   if(photoFunc.photo_img.width != 0){
   (function goSize(){
               a = ''
       if(photoFunc.photo_img.width  < 400){ 
           a = 400
       }else{
           a = photoFunc.photo_img.width
       }
       photoFunc.photo.style.width = a + 'px'
       photoFunc.photo.style.height = photoFunc.photo_img.height + 'px'
   })()
   clearInterval(intevalID)
   } 
   }, 30)
   ```
2. Функция вызывается по стандартному

   ```
   var intevalID = setInterval(function(){
   if(photoFunc.photo_img.width != 0){
       gosize()
   clearInterval(intevalID)
   } 
   }, 30)

   function goSize(){
   var a = ''
   if(photoFunc.photo_img.width  < 400){ 
       a = 400
   }else{
       a = photoFunc.photo_img.width
       }
   photoFunc.photo.style.width = a + 'px'
   photoFunc.photo.style.height = photoFunc.photo_img.height + 'px'
   ```

   }

Comment: один раз объявить и многократно вызывать, лучше, чем объявлять перед каждым вызовом

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Разница в контексте. Если вы определяете функцию по имени, замыкание происходит в момент определения. Если же вы используете функцию через `(function(){ ... })()`, замыкание происходит непосредственно в точке вызова.

[Пример](https://stackoverflow.com/q/643542/276994), где эта разница имеет значение:

```
var functions = [];
var i = 0;
function out() { 
    alert("i = " + i);
}
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    functions[i] = out;
}

var functions2 = [];
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    functions2[i] = (function(tmp) {
        return function() {
            alert("i = " + tmp);
        };
    })(i);
}

for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    functions[j](); // 
}

for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    functions2[j]();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

В первом случае функция будет недоступна для повторного использования где-нибудь в другом месте кода, во втором - доступна. Я бы использовал второй вариант.

Answer (score 0):

А вы разницу чувствуете, что означает конструкция

```
(function() {}())
```

и

```
function(){}
```

?